# Controlling the font size based on size of screen and the length of the words

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, font-size

**Situation**: I have a `<TextBlock />` that receives asynchronous content by a function.

**Problem**: Some times the text received is too long, and I don't want to wrap this text.

**Solution**: Reduce the font size acording the length of the text received so that the text received stays visible completely at screen..

**The problem with this solution**: How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider putting your TextBlock in a ViewBox control to stretch text accordingly.

Comment: Viewboxes needs to have a fixed size? Or Can they adjust according screen?

Comment: Can I define a minimum font size?

Comment: Viewboxes do not need to have a fixed size.   To define a minimum font size, you could instead have a fixed height for the viewbox.  The drawback on this solution is that the "view" of the text stretches in size rather than an increase in font.